# Split en caracteres especiales como '\' en java

Tags: java, variables, split

Hola me gustaria saber como le hago un split a caracteres especiales.
lo que estoy tratando de hacer es quitarle los \ a estos números.

```
String octa = "\344\215\214\362\034\016";
   String[] prueba = octa.split("\");
    for (int i = 0; i < prueba.length; i++) {


    System.out.println(":"+Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(prueba[i],8)));
     }
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Brayan, realiza el [tour] del sitio!. No olvides crear tus preguntas en base al documento [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Debes realizar un escape del carácter `\`  una opción es:

```
 String[] prueba = octa.split("\\\\");
```

Otra opción es usar la clase Pattern:

```
    String octa = "\344\215\214\362\034\016";
    String separator = "\\";
    String[] prueba = octa.split(Pattern.quote(separator));
```